# Windows server 2012 user/administrator missing programs

Tags: windows-server-2012, internet-explorer, user-profile, windows-explorer

I have the weirdest thing with windows server i have ever encountered.
When i log into the IIS server i have all my pined icons in the metro interface, my task bar pinned programs and my mapped shares in explorer.

Than when a other user logs on (has the same rights as me) he has lost all his pined icons on the metro interface and lost all pinned task bar programs. And Internet explorer and explorer won't open from the icon only if i run C: for explorer and find internet explorer as the executable.

And to make it even more strange, when that users logs into other servers or workstations there is no problem. He is the only user with this problem. So how do i fix this without deleting the user or reinstalling the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to solve this problem.

Log in with an account witch has administrator rights on the problem machine.
Go to C:\Users\ and rename the folder with the name of the problem account to account `name.old`.
Than remove the user from the local user list and check the register under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and if the account is still there remove it.

Restart the machine and login with the problem account.
Windows wil recreated the user profile, you can move files that where stored in the old user profile that we renamed and than delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you back up his profile then rename it, log him in and see if his environment comes back? Then you could copy back the obvious stuff he needs and the rest would have to be set again.